# How do you handle the Immolator move "Hand Crafted"?

Tags: dungeon-world, class

The move is as follows:

> You may use your hands in place of tools and fire to craft metal objects. Mundane weapons, armor and metal jewelry can all be formed from their raw components. You may unmake these things, as well, but to do so without time and safety might require that you Defy Danger first.

How does one handle this move? The answers I'm looking for are along these lines: time requirements, cost of raw materials, limits on things to be made, etc.

I had an Immolator recently make an entire set of armor for himself and made it take like a week (since he basically molded it to his own body). This move is so open-ended.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since the move says nothing about changing the time or materials or cost or limits, I would say that it's not meant to affect those things. It takes just as long and costs just as much to forge your metal object as it would on a forge. You just don't need a forge to do it, which means you can do it anywhere you like. (Well and it takes a little less time because you don't need to heat the forge)

The only limits are the blacksmithing skills of the Immolator, which is not a mechnical thing in DungeonWorld, so they're whatever the fiction demands.

Comment: I love this system lol

Answer (score 7):

Why not ask the Immolator what their ability is like?  "What does it look like when you craft things by hand?  Is it a quick process or does it take a long time?  Does prolonged use of this ability have any side effects on you?"  Developing the fiction around the move is a collaborative effort and a lot of players will have fun with introducing interesting quirks that can come into play later.

One thing to consider here is if the player tries to make the move super-powerful: "Yeah, I heat up the metal and reshape it really fast, like Terminator liquid metal style."  Well, later you can *show a downside to their class, race or equipment* when a miss on Burning Brand causes the heat to go out of control and melt the armor they crafted right off their body.

Comment: That's the spirit :)